# Printing Multiple Windows Using PrintVisual()

Tags: c#, wpf, printdialog

I'm currently using `PrintVisual()` in a wpf application to do printing. This is working perfectly at the moment, the only issue I now have is when processing large amounts of data I need to paginate, whereby I want to render the window multiple times to a buffer and then execute a print job. Currently `PrintVisual()` creates multiple print jobs, which works, but is not very eloquent.

I have attempted to use reflector to get the source for `PrintVisual()` in hopes of implementing that into an `IDocumentPaginatorSource`, unfortunately reflector is failing.

Perhaps I should try rending the window to a `FlowDocument`? Although I'm not too keen on having to code the printing layout.

Any suggestions?
Thanks In Advance!

Comment: Could you post some sample code of what you are doing.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

I came right by calling `RenderTargetBitmap()` on each page's canvas.